# Moment Generating function With Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

[image]

[image]

[image]

However i'm not sure about the result because in another calculation choose B seemed to be the answer.

Am I missing something? Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe this is not as mysterious as you're making it. For constant $K,$ just as one has $\sum_{i=1}^n K = nK,$ one also has $\prod_{i=1}^n K = K^n.$

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question. Stand by.....

Comment: $$\begin{align}
M_{bX_1,\ldots,bX_n} (t_1,\ldots,t_n) & = \operatorname{E}(e^{t_1(bX_1)\,+\,\cdots 
\,+\,t_n (bX_n)}) \\
& = \operatorname{E}(e^{(bt_1)X_1 \,+\,\cdots\,+\,(bt_n)X_n}) = M_{X_1,\ldots,X_n} (bt_1,\ldots,bt_n)
\end{align}$$